# How to convert rotation to 0 - 1 float

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an interactable lever in my VR game. I'm using a hinge joint for the rotation and that's working very well. I'd like to use the X-axis rotation to send out a variable called "outputFloat." My biggest issue is that I need to convert the rotation of the lever to a 0 - 1 float. I've been messing with everything for hours but I just cannot get something to work. I'll attach my code below.

```
    public class lever : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform leverArm;
    public float min;
    public float max;

    public float outputFloat;

    void Update()
    {
        Mathf.Clamp(leverArm.localRotation.x, min, max);
        outputFloat = leverArm.localRotation.x * max;
        outputFloat = 1 - outputFloat;

        Debug.Log(outputFloat);
    }

}
```

Comment: `transform.localRotation` is a [Quaternion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html). Unless you know exactly what you're doing, don't use the components of a Quaternion. Rather, you would probably want to use [`leverArm.localEulerAngles.x`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html) to get the x axis euler angle.

Answer (score 0):

You know already that the max is 360, so wouldn't this work?:

```
void Update()
{
    outputFloat = leverArm.localEulerAngles.x;
    outputFloat = 1 - Mathf.Abs(outputFloat/360);
    Debug.Log(outputFloat);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class lever : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform leverArm;
    public float min = 270f;
    public float max = 340f;

    public float outputFloat;

    void Update()
    {
        outputFloat = (leverArm.localEulerAngles.x - min) / (max - min);
        Debug.Log(outputFloat);
    }

}
```

Finally got it to work! Here's the code I used.